# Compiling Dolphin emulator beta

Tags: qt, cmake, compiler-errors, compilation, qt5

Moved from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338399/two-cursors-in-dolphin), because it's about compiling software.

**My original problem**: I want to play Super Mario Galaxy 2 with another player. But whatever keys I assign to move the cursor, it instead moves it all the way to the corner (or edge) of the screen. Linux theoretically has the ability to have multiple cursors (at least the display system "X" allows it), but from a research it looks like I would have to make major changes to the system to actually use it. And even then I doubt that Dolphin would support it.

**My current problem**: Relative motion of a cursor from keys is present in the current betas of Dolphin, but I can't get it installed. There are no regular installers for it, instead there are source downloads and [this tutorial](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux).

I installed [the dependencies](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux#Other_Linux_Distributions), [downloaded the beta](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux#Step_2_-_Get_the_Dolphin_Repository), [created and entered the "Build" directory](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux#Step_3_-_Building_Dolphin), but when I try `cmake ..`, I get this output:

```
-- Detected architecture: x86_64
-- X11 support enabled
-- Xrandr found
--  Found avcodec: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so
--  Found avformat: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so
--  Found avutil: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so
--  Found swresample: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so
--  Found swscale: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so
-- libav/ffmpeg found, enabling AVI frame dumps
-- libevdev/libudev found, enabling evdev controller backend
-- Using named pipes as controller inputs
-- Watching game memory for changes
-- Enabling analytics collection (subject to end-user opt-in)
-- Using static enet from Externals
-- Using static xxhash from Externals
-- Using shared zlib
-- Using static lzo from Externals
-- Using shared libpng
-- Using shared LibUSB
-- Found SFML 2.4 in /usr/include
-- Using shared SFML
-- Using shared miniupnpc
-- Could NOT find MBEDTLS (missing:  MBEDTLS_VERSION_OK) 
-- Using static mbed TLS from Externals
-- Using shared libcurl
-- Using static DiscordRPC from Externals
-- libsystemd found, enabling traversal server watchdog support
-- Using static gtest from Externals
-- Could NOT find OpenSLES (missing:  OPENSLES_LIBRARY OPENSLES_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- ALSA found, enabling ALSA sound backend
-- PulseAudio found, enabling PulseAudio sound backend
-- BlueZ found, enabling bluetooth support
CMake Error at Source/Core/DolphinQt/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible
with requested version "5.9".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.7.1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/fabian/dolphin_beta/dolphin-emu/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/fabian/dolphin_beta/dolphin-emu/Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The output of `apt-file search Qt5Config.cmake` is:

```
libaccounts-qt5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/AccountsQt5/AccountsQt5Config.cmake
libphonon4qt5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/phonon4qt5/Phonon4Qt5Config.cmake
libsignon-qt5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/SignOnQt5/SignOnQt5Config.cmake
libtelepathy-qt5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/TelepathyQt5/TelepathyQt5Config.cmake
qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
```

To be safe I installed all five of these packages. I also installed version 5.10 of Qt5-default from [here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/qt5-default/download), later also 5.11. I also installed qtbase5-private-dev, libreadline-dev and tried to install libpolarssl-dev, but [the page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/arm64/libpolarssl-dev/download) gave error messages for all four servers (the Taiwanian one just loads forever, the others give 404). Then I tried the [Qt installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5) and selected the latest stable version (5.11 I think) once and 5.9 once.
None of these steps helped, I still get the same output as at the beginning.

Here is a copy of `CMakeOutput.log` from when I last tried installing: https://pastebin.com/EP5qDGE9
Here is a copy of `CMakeError.log` from when I last tried installing: https://pastebin.com/9p4Ni0jE

My specs:
Debian 9.5
Cinnamon 3.2.7
Linux Kernel 4.9.0-8-amd64
Installed packages: https://pastebin.com/DeYAvJtu

Comment: Looks like CMake thinks that `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake` is for version 5.7, not 5.11 as you said.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Here are the contents of that file: https://pastebin.com/EWWwiBK6

Comment: QT version should be stored in the `Qt5ConfigVersion.cmake` file, near the `Qt5Config.cmake` one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That says 5.7.1: https://pastebin.com/JY4zZ9AR So what do I do then? What do I have to install or configure to make it work?

Comment: As the error message says, you need QT of version at least 5.9 for make the configuration proceed. QT 5.7.1 which you have doesn't for for this requirement.

Comment: When you updated Qt, did you update the dev (development) packages as well? (Otherwise, you may have a run-time which is up-to-date, and development packages which are old.) Sorry for my shot into blue. The closest system I've on my side is cygwin on Windows. There I learned to care about this.

Comment: Btw. the installed packages list you uploaded to pastebin shows Qt 5.7.1 only. (I looked for "libqt5".)

Comment: If you installed another version of Qt in a non-default place, you may tell cmake this. Found [How to pass a different Qt installation path to cmake?](https://github.com/KDAB/GammaRay/issues/213).

Comment: @Scheff What do I have to install specifically? Also, I am pretty sure I did not change any paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to the user [dugan](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/user/dugan-83260/) on linuxquestions.org! He solved my problem [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-games-33/compiling-dolphin-emulator-beta-on-debian-4175638912/page2.html#post5907817).

I just had to install Qt from a different source (I used the [Qt installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5), as mentioned in the question), to have a different version of it in another location. The reason for that is that many programs on Debian rely on an earlier version of Qt, so just updating it would break a lot, that's also why Synaptic&Co. don't update it.
Then I had to add the binary to the `PATH` variable, like so:

```
export PATH=/home/fabian/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/bin:$PATH
```

Then I was able to just install Dolphin beta regularly, like the [tutorial](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Building_Dolphin_on_Linux) says it.